# href tel usage in ios 5 safari makes browser go 1 page back in history

Tags: iphone, ios5, safari, href, tel

So I am just trying to initiate a call from a webpage, and that part works fine.
But when the call link is called and the note pops up if I want to call. Safari at the same time steps one page back in browsing history!

I am trying with two syntaxs as of now

```
<a>Click the phone number to initiate call: </a><a href="tel:+12345" class="call">Call</a><br>

<a href="tel:0123412345" target="_blank" rel="external" data-role="button">Phone me</a>
```

So if anyone knows how to avoid browser going back on press of tel link that would be great.